# Objective c block in a block

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, objective-c-blocks

Lot of blocks here!

I am trying to use blocks to perform an operation on each record present in a dictionary.

I created a weak reference of the strongRecordBlock and used that to call itself in the strongRecordBlock. It all worked fine until I introduced my actual operation (DataManager addRecord) that I need to perform which in turn is a block.
So there is an exception now, the weakRecordBlock is null after first iteration of the recursive loop. Can anybody please guide!

```
__weak __block void (^weakRecordBlock)(int i);

        void (^strongRecordBlock)(int) = ^(int i) {
            NSString *key = weakSelf.recordDictionary.allKeys[i];
            CSVRecord *record = [weakSelf.recordDictionary objectForKey:key];
            NSLog(@"%d %@", i, record.recordFullname);
            [[DataManager sharedInstance] addRecord:record onSuccess:^(NSString *objectId) {
                if (i < weakSelf.recordDictionary.allKeys.count-1) {
                    weakRecordBlock(i+1);//Crashes here
                }
                else {
                    completedBlock();
                }
            } onError:^(NSError *error) {
                onError(error);
            }];


        };
        weakRecordBlock = strongRecordBlock;
        strongRecordBlock(0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems is that you are trying to use weak pointer inside of block. And it lead to realising weak point after first run loop.

So you need to create strong reference to the weakRecordBlock inside of strongRecordBlock. So just add this line of code on top of your strongRecordBlock

```
 void (^strongPointerToWeakRecordBlock)(int i) = weakRecordBlock;
```

and replace **weakRecordBlock(i+1)** with **strongPointerToWeakRecordBlock(i+1)**

Answer (score 2):

RomanSalabay's answer is right. The problem is `-[DataManager addRecord:record onSuccess:]` executes its argument block *asynchronously*. Therefore, that block (the argument to `-[DataManager addRecord:record onSuccess:]`) needs to keep a strong reference to the objects and blocks used within, to keep them alive until the block runs; otherwise they can be deallocated by the time that block runs. But it captures a weak reference (`weakRecordBlock`). It needs to copy a strong reference instead. So you should assign the weak variable to a strong variable in the body of the outer block to let the inner block capture.